# How to find out which block is called?

Tags: magento2, admin, blocks, template

> module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml

has the following code:

```
<?php echo $block->getForm()->getHtml() ?>
```

How can I found out which block that is?#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always check the class of `$block` by saying:

```
<?php echo $block::class; ?>
```

The block for this template should be:
`Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Account.php` in `vendor/magento/module-sales`

Answer (score 3):

go to magento admin and navigation to system->configurations->advanced->developer and here you will see option " template path hints ", enable that ( for selected store view ).

Then you will see template paths and block which are being called on specific page.

Answer (score 3):

For that, block file is below...

```
module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Account.php
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kishan Patadia  right.

***Some additional info:***

**Please check below layout file :**

- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_form_account.xml`
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml`

From this files, you can find block class of this template file.